# Uploading Apps to the Android Market Invalid Icon Image Size

Tags: android

I'm trying to upload my first application, but when I select the apk file, I get the following message:

The icon for your application is not valid. Please use a 48x48 PNG.

The file was created in Fireworks, and is a 48x48 24 bit image named appicon.png.

Anyone know of any reason why I would still get this message?

Comment: Could be the bit size, try to change it to 16, 32 and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Never Mind, I found the problem. It was a bad value in my manifest file.